# How to rollback the new address auto-complete layout of Outlook 2016?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016

Few days ago, somehow, the Outlook 2016 layout of the autocomplete list of addresses has changed.
Now the list doesn't work very well and overflow the top of the screen:

[image]

Is there any way to revert this update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an known issue on Version 2104 (Build 13929.20296), as an workaround, you could try to revert your Office version like below:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\ClickToRun\OfficeC2RClient.exe" /update user updatetoversion=16.0.13901.20462

Comment: Incredible... thanks, it works.

Comment: The update is coming back again and again automatically. How to stop them?

Comment: Try to turn off auto-update: File>Office account>Uodate Options>Disable updates.

Comment: Here is an update :
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/401685/2104-1392920372-outlook-makes-address-look-ahead-u.html
Looks like the issue has been fixed in latest version of Outlook, it's recommended to update your Outlook to check :)